# Simulate "ENTER" Selenium

Tags: python, xpath

Hello ^^ I am currently coding on Selenium (python webdriver) and I would like to know the command to simulate the "Enter" touch in the script in order to validate a step. How can I do ?
Thank you ^^

Answer (score 0):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
driver = webdriver.Firefox()

# Navigate to url

driver.get("http://www.google.com")

# Enter "webdriver" text and perform "ENTER" keyboard action

driver.find_element(By.NAME, "q").send_keys("webdriver" + Keys.ENTER)
```

This can be found on their docs page.  Basically you want to import Keys from selenium.webdriver.common.keys and then use element.send_keys(Keys.Enter) as needed.

[source](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/webdriver/keyboard/)

Comment: it does not work. I'm actually trying to automatically hit the "Enter" key on my program in order to validate data on a site (instead of clicking on connect "